# How to handle redirect from proxied server in webpack-dev-server proxy?

Tags: laravel, nginx, webpack, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

I'm having a webpack-dev-server enabled with watcher and reload on every change.

This frontend dev server is in docker container, and is proxying everything to another docker container, backend, which is using server-side-rendering.

So, `frontend` has exposed port `8080` to host machine. When you visit `localhost:8080`, it proxies everything to `nginx:8000`, which then servers php files (including the HTML code of this server).

```js
devServer: {
   port: 8080,
   host: '0.0.0.0', // to accept connections from outside container
   disableHostCheck: true,

   watchOptions: {
      poll: 1000
   },
   writeToDisk: true,

 
   proxy: {
      "**": {
         target: "http://nginx:80", // Proxy to backend
         changeOrigin: true,
         secure: false,
         logLevel: "debug",
      }
   }
}
```

That works fine, unless the server sends redirect. In that case, the proxied response has location `nginx:8000<redirected_url>`.

How to handle such case?

According to [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy), webpack dev server uses a [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options).

I tried it's options `autoRewrite:true` and `hostRewrite:true` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is custom interceptor in [onProxyRes](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware?tab=readme-ov-file#http-proxy-events), which handles the redirects.

Rewrites the location, which browser should be redirected to with current dev server url + the rest of the URL where proxied server redirect pointed to.

```js
   proxy: {
                "**": {
                    target: "http://nginx:80", // Proxy to backend
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    secure: false,

                    // This handles the redirects
                    onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
                        if ([301, 302, 307, 308].indexOf(proxyRes.statusCode) > -1 && proxyRes.headers.location) {
                            const originalUrl = new URL(req.originalUrl, req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host);
                            const redirectLocation = new URL(proxyRes.headers['location']);

                            // Rewrite the location to devServer origin and the path + query string + hash from response
                            proxyRes.headers['location'] = originalUrl.origin + redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search + redirectLocation.hash;
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `changeOrigin: false`. This will not rewrite the origin on all request - if your server is creating some URLs in responses from $request->url(), rewriting origin will modify all links - what you probably don't want to.